# Unable to connect Azure DevOps and Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created an automated Service Principal from the service requests on Azure Devops with sufficient permissions. Now, when I am trying to create an artifact which is an ML model (registered) it is not auto populating the registered models and resulting in an error.

I am using a free trial Azure account and attempting to implement CI CD for ML. I turned my firewall off and attempted as well but still the issue persists.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Service Principal is not assigned the role in the appropriate subscription.

You need to grant the service principal Azure subscription access permission:

Login **Azure portal**->**All servic**e->**Subscriptions**->click your **subscription**->**Access control(IAM**)->**Add role assignment**->assign the correct role to your service principal

Refer to [Use the portal to create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role) and [Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current) for details.

Comment: Hi Andi Li! My SP has contributor role on the AML instance and subscription.

Comment: @TheHumanSpider Can you please try to [Sign in with a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-with-a-service-principal) by running the Azure CLI to check if the SP is associated to the subscription correctly?  `az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>`

Comment: yes after running with the above command I get a JSON with state 'enabled'. Hope I have followed your steps correctly.

Comment: To add I am following this page https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-air-aiagility.vss-services-azureml